# Draw Angular/Conical Gradient in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, gradient

What is the best / fastest / easiest way to draw an angular gradient in OpenGL ES 2.0?

It should look like this, with editable colors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a huge variety of ways to do most things in OpenGL.

Off the top of my head I'd probably use a series of triangle strips drawn with color blending.